# geom_tile heatmap with different high fill colours based on factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm interested in building a heatmap with `geom_tile` in **ggplot2** that uses a different gradient high color based on a factor.

The plot below creates the plot where the individual tiles are colored blue or red based on the `xy_type`, but there is no gradient.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data=mydata, aes(x=factor(myx), y=myy, fill=factor(xy_type))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
```

The plot below does not use the `xy_type` factor to choose the color, but I get a single group gradient based on the `xy_avg_value`.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data=mydata, aes(x=factor(myx), y=myy, fill=xy_avg_value))
```

Is there a technique to blend these two plots?  I can use a `facet_grid(xy_type ~ .)` to create separate plots of this data, with the gradient.  As this is ultimately going to be a map (x~y coordinates), I'd like to find a way to display the different gradient together in a single `geom_tile` map.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In general, **ggplot2** does not permit multiple scales of a single type (i.e. multiple colour or fill scales), so I suspect that this isn't (easily) possible.

The best nearest approximation I can come up with is this:

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(1:5,1:5))
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))
df$grp <- rep(letters[1:2],length.out = nrow(df))

ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2,fill = factor(grp),alpha = z)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','blue'))
```

[image]

But it's going to be tough to get a sensible legend.

Comment: That solves the problem perfectly for my use.  The dual legend is pretty straightforward to read in my application.

Thanks for the help!