# Stagger geom_tile for same point on y axis and use two color scales for the two tiles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with which I'm trying to use geom_tile to show the differences in the column "value" for each point in time "day" (x axis) across each site "zid" (y axis). 
[image]

Now the problem is that for each site and each time interval, I may or may not have another observation with a different treatment (column "Num" in the data sample below). I would like to make my geom_tile plot such that each of the two treatments can be stacked on top of each other yet corresponding to the same point on the y axis (column "zid" in the data sample below). In order to differentiate the two treatments corresponding to the same zid and same day, I would like to use two separate color schemes for each of the treatments.

I've scoured the web and cant find anyway to do this. I'm not opposed to using another geom structure like geom_rect if anyone has any ideas as to how to achieve what I'm looking for.

EDIT: Per the advice by @JasonAizkalns, here is a hand-drawn mockup of what I'm looking for -- except instead of two scales of solid colors for the two treatments, I'd like two gradient scales (which I couldn't render with my magic markers). [image: hand-drawn mockup]

EDIT2: I've tried faceting, but it's far from what I'm hoping for (see comment below.)[image]

The ggplot code I've used is here, followed by the reproducible data:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=as.factor(zid), y=day))+
  geom_tile(aes(ymin=day,ymax=day+1, fill=value), color="white", linetype=5)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red",high = "steelblue")+
  coord_flip()
```

Data sample:

```
dat <- structure(list(zid = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 29L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 32L, 
33L, 34L), .Label = c("X237", "X238", "X239", "X240", "X241", 
"X242", "X243", "X244", "X245", "X246", "X247", "X248", "X249", 
"X250", "X251", "X252", "X253", "X254", "X255", "X256", "X257", 
"X258", "X259", "X260", "X261", "X262", "X263", "X264", "X265", 
"X266", "X267", "X268", "X269", "X270", "X271", "X272", "X273", 
"X274", "X275", "X276", "X277", "X282", "X283", "X284", "X285", 
"X286", "X287", "X288"), class = "factor"), value = c(350L, 456L, 
779L, 594L, 370L, 192L, 132L, 471L, 363L, 290L, 406L, 355L, 342L, 
329L, 208L, 207L, 250L, 441L, 384L, 432L, 269L, 275L, 392L, 306L, 
367L, 208L, 241L, 226L, 212L, 237L, 210L, 252L, 274L, 297L, 292L, 
281L, 308L, 291L, 280L, 431L, 315L, 447L, 213L, 532L, 372L, 693L
), num = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), day = c(237L, 238L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 251L, 
254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 265L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 
273L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 
270L, 271L, 268L, 269L, 270L)), .Names = c("zid", "variable", 
"value", "num", "day"), row.names = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 
21L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 48L, 51L, 54L, 57L, 
60L, 63L, 66L, 69L, 72L, 75L, 78L, 81L, 84L, 87L, 90L, 93L, 96L, 
99L, 102L, 117L, 120L, 123L, 126L, 129L, 132L, 135L, 138L, 141L, 
144L, 147L, 150L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This might be easier for other to help you if you strip this down to only a few rows and show a sketch of your desired output.

Comment: Thanks @JasonAizkalns for your comment. I just edited my post to include a sketch of my desired output.

Comment: What about using facets? Along the lines of  `ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(num), y=day)) +   ... the rest of your code .. + facet_grid(zid~.)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user20650. I tried facets but the truth is I want the two observations that correspond to the same day and site but have different treatments stacked right on top of each other for ease of comparison, and not side by side as I would get with a facet. (see my silly drawing for an example of what I'm describing)

Comment: Silvan; it is not perfect, but looks fairly close to your drawing (+1 for the hand drawn piccy btw. The different treatments are in the same facet, and so are right next to each other.

Comment: @user20650, it seems I'm not following you. In trying the facet example as you suggested, the different treatments are in the two facets (and have the same color scheme contrary to what I want).  I've edited my post above to show you what I've produced with the facet bit. Would you kindly show me what you're getting at? And how it differs from the graphic in "EDIT #2 above"?

Comment: ph i faceted differently... `ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(num), y=day)) +
  geom_tile(aes(ymin=day, ymax=day+1,  fill=value),  color="white", linetype=5) +   scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red",high = "steelblue") +
  coord_flip() +   facet_grid(zid~.) +   theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "null"))`. But needs work on the treatment colours.

Comment: I got: Error in theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "null")) : 
  could not find function "unit"

Comment: sorry: `library(grid)` or `grid::unit`. but you could leave the theme out to see how it looks

Comment: Youre welcome... to get the different colours you can try the trick from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232525/geom-tile-heatmap-with-different-high-fill-colours-based-on-factor) where the 'fill' is mapped to the treatment group and `alpha`to the value.  ie. `ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(num), y=day, fill=factor(num), alpha=value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(ymin=day, ymax=day+1)) +   scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','blue','green')) +   coord_flip() +   facet_grid(zid~.)`. (note three colours were defined as there are three values of num)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From User20650's ingenious answer below in the comments:

```
library(grid)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(num), y=day)) + geom_tile(aes(ymin=day, ymax=day+1, fill=value), color="white", linetype=5) + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red",high = "steelblue") + coord_flip() + facet_grid(zid~.) + theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "null")).
```