# geom_tile single color as 0, then color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to produce a heat map where with a color pallet of green to red, but values of 0 are in white. I got started with [geom_tile heatmap with different high fill colours based on factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232525/geom-tile-heatmap-with-different-high-fill-colours-based-on-factor) and others on SO but can't quite get what I need. For example, with the following database:

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(1:10,1:10))
df$z <- sample(0:10, nrow(df), replace=T)
```

I can create this plot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2,fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

[image]
But I want the values equal to zero to be white. So this gets part way there:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2,fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red", limits=c(1, 10))
```

[image]

And this gets 0 as white but I lose the green to red:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2,fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]

And I can't use brewer scales at all (though I think I'm missing something simple based on the error).

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2,fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_brewer("Greens")
```

### Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Should I just replace 0 with NA? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_gradientn()`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "green", "red"), values = c(0,0.1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: A heads-up for who's using this solution: `values` must be in [0,1]. If you want to work in different intervals, you can use scales::rescale(). E.g., in the original example: `values=rescale(c(0,1,10))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have NA values in your data, you can modify your 2nd plot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2,fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red", limits=c(1, 10),na.value="white")
```

The advantage of this solution (in comparison to the one by @erc) is, that only the values below your limits are white, while in the solution by @erc, the values between zero and your limit are colored as a gradient so some of them can also be white-ish (i.e. be on the white side of the gradient, visually indistinguishable from white).