# Change legend title position with no change in labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building off a question asked earlier, [geom_tile single color as 0...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030624/geom-tile-single-color-as-0-then-color-scale) It starts with the following code and the provided answer code creates the plot:

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(1:10,1:10))
df$z <- sample(0:10, nrow(df), replace=T)
# provided answer from SO
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "green", "red"), values = c(0,0.1,1))
```

[image]

I would like to move the legend to the bottom with the legend title on top and centered. The code and result are here:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "green", "red"), values = c(0,0.1,1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position="top",label.position = "bottom"))
```

[image]

Repositioning the legend works and the title is on "top" but I lost the continuous scale and can't center the title. There are a number of informative q&a on SO about changing legend title position but none seem to have the problem of having a continuous legend changed to discreet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is  how you want it?

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = Var1,y = Var2, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "green", "red"),
                       values = c(0, 0.1, 1)) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title.position = "top",
                                title.hjust = .5,
                                label.position = "bottom"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you yes, so simple. So the lesson here for me is that "legend" changes to a discreet variable to display where I wanted to use "colourbar" in the guide.